# How to remove non-ascii infected rows in my csv

Tags: python

I have a very large csv file that looks like this:

keywords,impressions
descargar juegos gratis,951
ãƒ‘ã‚½ã‚³ãƒ³ kakaku com,451
corporate meeting,155
rental cars,356
smart,1224
guitar tab,064
è‹±è¯­ç¿»è¯‘,160

I have read the file into a dict like so:

```
# Read the CSV
filename = argv[1]
csvfile = open(filename, 'r')
csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
  rows.append(row)
```

How would I delete rows with non-ascii characters so that I only end up with:

keywords,impressions
descargar juegos gratis,951
corporate meeting,155
rental cars,356
smart,1224
guitar tab,064

In short: if any non-ascii characters are present in the row the whole row must be deleted.

Thanks!

Comment: ... Why not just properly decode it as UTF-8 instead?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv, sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
csvfile = open(filename, 'r')
csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
  try:
      row['keywords'].decode('ascii')
      rows.append(row) 
  except UnicodeDecodeError:
      pass

print rows
```

Comment: Always open a csv file in binary mode (Python 2.x) or with `newline=''` (Python 3.x)

Comment: Why open in binary mode? it looks fine to me that way

Comment: @datayoda: Text mode on Windows messes things up. Reading: csv fields can have embedded `\r`, `\n`, and `chr(26)` characters. Writing: you'll get `\r\r\n` instead of `\r\n` as the row separator. "Works OK with my files on my platform" only gets you so far.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way: you can try to decode it, and catch the exception.

```
try:
    string.decode('ascii')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print "Not ascii"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are interested, you could well be throwing good data away; it doesn't look like random rubbish to me:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ucd
>>> for x in open('unascii.txt').read().decode('utf8', 'replace'):
...     if x > u'\x7f': print repr(x), ucd.name(x, '<no name>')
...
u'\u30d1' KATAKANA LETTER PA
u'\u30bd' KATAKANA LETTER SO
u'\u30b3' KATAKANA LETTER KO
u'\u30f3' KATAKANA LETTER N
u'\u82f1' CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-82F1
u'\u8bed' CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-8BED
u'\u7ffb' CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-7FFB
u'\u8bd1' CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-8BD1
>>>
```

Note that the file decodes successfully using UTF-8 (as @Ignacio hinted), and the first bunch of apparent gibberish actually makes sense (Japanese pasocom == "personal computer", written in Katakana) and the second bunch (英语翻译) is detected by Google Translate as Chinese and is translated to "English Translation".

Comment: You are right the data is not garbage but I needed a quick way to restrict to English only Keywords

Comment: @datayoda: First two words of `descargar juegos gratis` don't look like English to me.